# ReeantrantLock and Condition variable

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

Hello:) I'm learning about the Re-entrant Lock and the condition variable in Java. I happened to come across this [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078848/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-java-101-the-next-generation-java-concurrency-without-the-pain-part-2.html?page=2). In the tutorial, the author provides a Producer-Consumer example utilizing the ReentrantLock:

```
public class CondDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Shared s = new Shared();
      new Producer(s).start();
      new Consumer(s).start();
   }
}

class Shared
{
   private volatile char c;
   private volatile boolean available;
   private final Lock lock;
   private final Condition condition;

   Shared()
   {
      c = '\u0000';
      available = false;
      lock = new ReentrantLock();
      condition = lock.newCondition();
   }

   Lock getLock()
   {
      return lock;
   }

   char getSharedChar()
   {
      lock.lock();
      try
      {
         while (!available) {
            try
            {
               condition.await();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
               ie.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         available = false;
         condition.signal();
      }
      finally
      {
         lock.unlock();
         return c;
      }
   }

   void setSharedChar(char c)
   {
      lock.lock();
      try
      {
         while (available) {
            try
            {
               condition.await();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
               ie.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         this.c = c;
         available = true;
         condition.signal();
      }
      finally
      {
         lock.unlock();
      }
   }
}

class Producer extends Thread
{
   private final Lock l;

   private final Shared s;

   Producer(Shared s)
   {
      this.s = s;
      l = s.getLock();
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
      {
         l.lock();
         s.setSharedChar(ch);
         System.out.println(ch + " produced by producer.");
         l.unlock();
      }
   }
}

class Consumer extends Thread
{
   private final Lock l;

   private final Shared s;

   Consumer(Shared s)
   {
      this.s = s;
      l = s.getLock();
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      char ch;
      do
      {
         l.lock();
         ch = s.getSharedChar();
         System.out.println(ch + " consumed by consumer.");
         l.unlock();
      }
      while (ch != 'Z');
   }
}
```

Are the methods `l.lock()` and `l.unlock()` in the `Producer` and `Consumer` unnecessary? I notice we have already applied the lock/unlock in the `Shared` object's `getSharedChar()` and `setSharedChar()` methods. Or is this a suggested pattern to use the condition variables?

Is this is a not good practice, can you provide a link for a better example?

Thanks:)

Comment: Hmm, weird. Reading this code, it appears to me a locked lock can be locked again - shouldn't that throw an Exception or something?

Comment: No that's the basic of lock reentrance. However, when obtain the lock have [count of acquisition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#getHoldCount--) to ensure lock releasing is done at the right place.

Comment: But what's the benefit for obtaining multiple locks?

Comment: It let's you design features where you don't have to rely on the code path. For example you can have a public method `foo()` which execute a critical code (thus require lock), then it call another public method `bar()` which also do critical things. As both methods are public, there's no easy way to  know in which context `bar()` is called. If you have some experience in Transaction management, the same logic apply. You don't know if your transaction is bound to your method or to higher caller. But transaction must be released at the same block level it has been opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's neither necessary, neither a pattern.

IMHO This is ugly redundant lock used to have clean output. I mean ugly because there's no try-finally to ensure first level unlock and it exposes internal state of `Shared` API.

To go deeper in learning Java concurrency, you can obtain same result using [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) or [Exchanger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I have already said that's just a "comestic" lock so neither necessary, neither pattern. I have explicitly add my answer.

Comment: Is there a better example about how to use ReentrantLock and Condition variable?

Comment: Have you take a look at [Condition documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) ? You can also have a look at [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html). I have greatly appreciated [Java Concurrent Animated](http://www.jconcurrent.com/). I haven't read them but [Concurrent Programming in Java](http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/bookshop/detail.asp?item=160479) and [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/bookshop/detail.asp?item=100000000112623) are famous

Comment: Furthermore any application of `synchronized`/`wait`/`notify` also apply. The main differences are `Lock` API isn't block bound (for the worst and for the better) and you can have many groups of `wait`/`notify` by using many `Condition` instances.

Comment: Which link are you refering to ? I have posted 7 links :x I have answered the original question about necessity or supposed pattern without any link. The two first ones are just reference about other Java SE classes which provides equivalent functionalities (I may add code samples but it's more an advice/hint than an answer). For the comment question, it asks for resources but doesn't direct refer to the original question, so I commented with 2 official documentation link (which are supposed to be the minimum available resources). The final ones are an application and two books.